# is it possible to disconnect from a bluetooth device in swift?

Tags: bluetooth, swift4, eaaccessory

**short question**
Is it possible to disconnect from a bluetooth device in swift? If so, how?

**background**

I would like to disconnect from my bluetooth device programmatically using swift 4 because I am working with a 3rd party bluetooth library and am noticing that when I call their commands to 'close the connection', that my instance variable of type

```
EAAccessoryManager.shared().connectedAccessories.count
```

is still equal to 1, and my EAAccessory instance shows that my connection is open, however my 3rd party library ConnectionManager shows my connection as closed (because I call the command to close it). However, apparently calling this 3rd party library ConnectionManager's 'close connection' function is not enough to actually clear the instance variables of EAAccessoryManager.shared() and EAAccessory

```
EAAccessoryManager.shared().connectedAccessories
```

is get-only, so I cannot set the connected accessories to an empty array.

Comment: iOS can not set bluetooth On, Off funtionality, this is user side to enable and disable.

Comment: so basically the apple API does not provide a way to disconnect from bluetooth devices? that is what I was thinking and gather, but am not 100% sure yet